# why we need to identify the entity and value object?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In Domain Driven Design,domain objects are fall into two categories,entity and value object.It is very easy to make out which is entity,which is value object,but i don't know why we have to do that?Before the advent of DDD, we model the domain without entity and value object.After the DDD was put forwar,we use entity and value object to classify domain object, so what is the advantage of such classification?

Comment: Would you model a Human as a Car? What problems could that cause in the system? Well that's about the question your are asking. Could you explain why you think it doesn't matter to model an Entity as a Value Object and vice-versa? It would make the answer far more concise.

Comment: @plalx Before the advent of DDD, we model the domain without entity and value object.After the DDD was put forwar,we use entity and value object to classify domain object, so what is the advantage of such classification?

Comment: "Before the advent of DDD, we model the domain without entity and value object" That's not true at all. Entities and Value Objects were always part of every OO designs since the day OO is born, it's just that we did not use those specific names to describe these concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Before the advent of DDD, we model the domain without entity and value object.After the DDD was put forwar,we use entity and value object to classify domain object, so what is the advantage of such classification?

You should review Chapter 5 ("A Model Expressed in Software") of the [Blue Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

Evans writes:

> Defining objects that clearly follow one pattern or the other makes the objects less ambiguous and lays out the path toward specific choices for robust design.
>
> Tracking the identity of ENTITIES is essential, but attaching identity to other objects can hurt system performance, add analytical work, and muddle the model by making all objects look the same.
>
> ... bidirectional associations between two VALUE OBJECTS just make no sense.  Without identity, it is meaningless to say that an object points back to the same VALUE OBJECT that points to it.  The most you could say is that it points to an object that is equal to the one pointing to it, but you would have to enforce that invariant somewhere.

My own summary would be this: recognizing that some domain concepts are entities is useful, because it encourages the designer to acknowledge that identity, continuity, and life cycle are important concerns for the entity in this domain.  Similarly, recognizing that a concept is a value immediately frees you from those concerns, bringing your attention to their immutable nature and equivalence.

Answer (score 3):

> domain objects are fall into two categories,

Actually, no, **objects** are a possible *implementation* of a domain **Concept** , which is basically just information, not code. A concept can be an Entity because it makes sense to identify it in a uniquely and consistent manner, regardless how it changes over time (e.g: a Customer can change their name but it's the same customer. 2 customers with the same name are not necessarily the same person).

A Value Object (a name that still reminds us that DDD started a bit too coupled to OOP) represent a Domain concept that it's just a value. Or more precisely, the business only cares about its value. If you change it, it's another value all together. Basically, 5 dollars is 5 dollars, you don't really care which is which, any of them is good enough, because only the **value** is important.

Another thing is, as a domain modeler you **identify** the nature of a concept based on how the business looks at a concept. The business tells you what they care about.

Now, that we know that a concept can be a Entity, we can select a certain instance of it (User with Id 3). You can't do that with VO, because a VO doesn't have an identity.

Even more, when we *identify* aggregates, most of the time, the aggregate components (other concepts) are mostly VOs, because they usually are just values (but they do respect business constraints).

So, in conclusion, we classify concepts into Entity and VO, because

- The business sees them in this manner: uniquely identifiable or just value
- Entities keep their identity regardless how they change (obviously the identity itself is read-only), we treat each one as unique
- VO are values that can be used interchangeably, we don't care which is which as long as they represent the same value (which itself, as an implementation detail can be a complex - composite - value). Also, a VO by its nature is immutable, so we know that we can't change it without becoming another value.